# complex MySQL query joins and bulky fetched array with repeated unwanted values and variables beeded to be presented as an associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, fetch

edited:

tables structres:
users:
userID
userName
userEmail
userCat

DocumentsTable:
DocID
DocHeadletter
DocText
DocDateTime

DocOwnersTable: many-many relationships [Doc*users]
DocID
userID

Diagnoses table:
DiagnosisID
DiagnosesTitle

DocDDiagnosesTables: many-many relationship [Doc*Diagnoses]
DocID
DiagnosisID

DocADiagnosesTable:many-many relationship [Doc*Diagnoses]
DocID
DiagnosisID

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Documents.DocID as DocID, 
    DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisID as DDiagnosis, ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisID as AddOnDiagnoseis, 
    DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisTitle as DDiagnosis, ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisTitle as AddOnDiagnoseis, 
    DocHeadletter, DocText as DocText, DocDateTime,
    ownersN.userName
FROM  Documents
INNER JOIN DocOwners as owners on Documents.DocID = owners.DocID
INNER JOIN users as ownersN on ownersN.userID = owners.userID
INNER JOIN DocDDiagnosis as DDiagnosis ON Documents.DocID = DDiagnosis.DocID
INNER JOIN diagnoses as DDiagnosisN ON DDiagnosis.DiagnosisID = DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisID
INNER JOIN DocADiagnosis as ADiagnosis ON Documents.DocID = ADiagnosis.DocID
INNER JOIN diagnoses as ADiagnosisN ON ADiagnosis.DiagnosisID = ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisID
WHERE Documents.DocID = $DocID
```

I have like 5 tables with relational structure.
users, documents, diagnoses.
logically, any document woud have muliple users associated with it, and multple Diagnoses at sometimes.

the joins are expected to fetch the relivent usersnames, diagnoses names and make available for the view formating...

the expected data should look like this:

```
array (9) = (DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> array(11, 15, 17), DocDiagnoses=>array(3, 5, 7) ...);
```

then I suppose I could use the array above to dynamically create a view like this:

```
Document ID:12345
Created at: 12/12/1235 @ 11:33 AM. By user name (for the first name in the userNames array).

Document text 

Diagnosis: (Diagnoses names list) additional Diagnoses: (additional Diagnoses names...)

Issued by: (list of user names).
```

however, this has been a painfull error trials for the past like 5 days...

when I created the MySQL query I was in a beg pridicment. when I use $Xxx->fetch(\PDO::fetch_asso) I only get one row of the expected result. when I use $Xxx->fetchAll(\PDO::fetch_asso) I get a bulky multidimensional array with internal arrays each of which include the needed key->value pair but with the keys associated with many values having only single value each time.

what is needed is a multidimentional array with the needed internal arrays that have their corrosponding array of values. which would help sorting and formating the desired data for the view.

like so:

```
array (9) = (DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> array(11, 15, 17), DocDiagnoses=>array(3, 5, 7) ...);
```

which I guess would make available to me the final view as such:
[illistrative Example:]
douemtn ID:10233
associated with: user name(ID:11), user name(ID:15), ..
has the diagnoses: diagnosis so and so (ID:3),diagnosis so and so (ID:5), ...
done in date and time.... etc

instead I get either: [with fetch(..)]

```
array(9) = (DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 11, DocDiagnoses=> 3 ...);
```

or

....................: with [fetchAll(...)]

```
array(30) = (
[0] => array = (DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 11, DocDiagnoses=> 3 ...);
[1] => array {DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 15, DocDiagnoses=>3 ...}
[2] => array {DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 17, DocDiagnoses=>3 ...}
[3] => array {DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 11, DocDiagnoses=>5 ...}
[4] => array {DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 11, DocDiagnoses=>5 ...}
[5] => array {DocID => 1235, DocUsers=> 11, DocDiagnoses=>5...}
....
..
..
and so on!
)
```

I tried to use arrays functions and non seems to work as desired... I tried arrays functions , array_diff, array_itersect... didnt work. the result was empty..

I feel stuck and I couldn`t get arround this issue although I guess it could be easily solved.

Comment: I woiuld start by EDITING your post and provide. list of each table and its structure of applicable columns, especially the keys that relate between them, and the descriptive columns you want in your final output.  Then, show the type and SAMPLE of information you expect to get out of the query, then myself and others can offer better assistance.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply, DRapp! I did as you suggested. I thought of doing so at first but then thought that lengthy post wouldn`t be better than a consice one captureing the essense of the matter. thanks again.

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" to your title, or post the answer in the question. There is a section below for answers, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75403868/edit) and move the solution to the answers section to properly close this question.

Comment: Sure, I did as you suggested. thanks for the guidence.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured and is working fine till now is to use GROUP_CONCAT( along with the DISTINCT ).

The group_concat plus the Group By the desired ID would produce a comma separated string that would work just fine as an array from which the list of multivalue fields would be fetched associatively. (i.e users, diagnoses ids and names).

Then the DISTINCT will efficiently, I guess, take care of the repetition of the related values.

So the final working SQL:

```
SELECT Documents.DocID as DocID, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisID) as DDiagnosis, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisID) as AddOnDiagnoseis, 
    DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisTitle as DDiagnosis, ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisTitle as AddOnDiagnoseis, 
    DocHeadletter, DocText as DocText, DocDateTime,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT owners.userID), ownersN.userName
FROM  Documents
INNER JOIN DocOwners as owners on Documents.DocID = owners.DocID
INNER JOIN users as ownersN on ownersN.userID = owners.userID
INNER JOIN DocDDiagnosis as DDiagnosis ON Documents.DocID = DDiagnosis.DocID
INNER JOIN diagnoses as DDiagnosisN ON DDiagnosis.DiagnosisID = DDiagnosisN.DiagnosisID
INNER JOIN DocADiagnosis as ADiagnosis ON Documents.DocID = ADiagnosis.DocID
INNER JOIN diagnoses as ADiagnosisN ON ADiagnosis.DiagnosisID = ADiagnosisN.DiagnosisID
WHERE Documents.DocID = $DocID
```

thank you all and hope this will help someone in the future.

Regards,